# How could I solve Invalid driver requested Session_session_id Error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using Community Auth Codeigniter authentication package.

After login, I'm getting the following view error:

> Invalid driver requested: Session_session_id

I've looked at documentation and searched for a solution with no luck.

Config file: http://pastebin.com/Nn7JeUDB

Debug is set to 2. The output is:

```
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> CI_Session routines successfully run
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Session class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Encryption: Auto-configured driver 'openssl'.
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Encryption: OpenSSL initialized with method AES-128-CBC.
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Encryption Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> XSS Filtering completed
DEBUG - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> XSS Filtering completed
ERROR - 2016-01-17 06:15:32 --> Invalid driver requested: Session_session_id
```

Session Config.php

```
$config['sess_driver']          = 'cookie';
$config['sess_valid_drivers']   = array();
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: What is version of CI?

Comment: @Tpojka it's codeigniter 3

Comment: Please re edit your question with your session configuration on config.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 updated

Comment: The sessions does not look like codeigniter 3 I do not see a session path.

Comment: You're right, there's something weird here. I'm using a 'terminal.com' public image which has 3.0-dev. Thank you for you help @wolfgang1983 . I will try of course a new install with latest CI3

Comment: Here is the codeigniter database session driver user guide for CI3 versions https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver